# Universal property of l^p-spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, category-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, universal-property

The category $\mathsf{Ban_1}$ of Banach spaces together with short linear maps (i.e. those of norm $\leq 1$) seems to have a natural construction which interpolates between coproduct and product:

Let $p \in [1,\infty]$ and let $(V_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of Banach spaces over $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$. Then we may define a new Banach space $\bigoplus^p_{i \in I} V_i$ (how is this usually denoted?) as follows: The points are the sequences $(v_i)_{i \in I}$ with $v_i \in V_i$ and $\sum_{i \in I} \lVert v_i \rVert^p < \infty$. We let $\lVert (v_i)_{i \in I} \rVert := (\sum_{i \in I} \lVert v_i \rVert^p)^{1/p}$. For $p=\infty$ this has to be interpreted as $\lVert (v_i)_{i \in I} \rVert := \sup_{i \in I} \lVert v_i \rVert < \infty$. For $V_i=\mathbb{K}$ we get the usual space $l^p(I)$.

- If $p=1$, then $\bigoplus^1_{i \in I} V_i$ is the coproduct of $(V_i)_{i \in I}$.
- If $p=\infty$, then $\bigoplus^{\infty}_{i \in I} V_i$ is the product of $(V_i)_{i \in I}$.

**Question.** Does $\bigoplus^p_{i \in I} V_i$ have a useful universal property if $1<p<\infty$?

If necessary, you may work in a different category than $\mathsf{Ban_1}$. But would be nice if this category does not depend on $p$.

Comment: I imagine they could have some interesting properties in particular categories of Banach spaces, like those with [type/cotype](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/type+%28functional+analysis%29) lying within a specified interval. This is just a wild guess, though, and I have more or less only heard about the notion of type and cotype.

Comment: To incorporate $p$ index into categorical framework you need to narrow your category and impose additional structures on your Banach spaces. For example, take a look at this fact: if for a Banach lattive $E$ there exists a function $f:\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\Vert x+y\Vert=f(\Vert x\Vert,\Vert y\Vert)$ whenever $x,y\in E$ are disjoint, then $E$ is an $L_p$ or $C(K)$-space.